# replace the text of a variable

Tags: javascript, replace, var

I am trying to replace the text from one variable to another but this tells me: **newLinkRef is not defined**

```
<script>
    $('.sous_img_montureCard').click(function(){

        var idMiniatureRef = $(this).attr('id');
        var linkRef = $(this).parents('.montureCard').children('.CardReferenceEnvies').children('.divCardRef').children('.sousDivCardRef').children('p');

        newLinkRef.replace(linkRef, idMiniatureRef);
        $(this).parents('.montureCard').children('.CardReferenceEnvies').children('.divCardRef').children('.sousDivCardRef').children('p').html(newLinkRef);
    });
</script>
```

I had succeeded with

```
var newLinkRef = linkRef + idMiniatureRef;
```

but that adds [OBJECT OBJECT]3CLA02A

and I just want 3CLA02A

Comment: Show us more code,please.

Comment: `linkRef` is a jQuery object, that’s why you get `[OBJECT OBJECT]` when trying to force it into a string context. If you want to work with the value of an attribute of one of those element(s?) you selected there - then you need to go and read the value of that attribute first. (It is rather unclear what exactly you want here though - you are selecting `p` elements on the last level there, those are not links to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't defined `newLinkRef` before. Define it, then replace.

Comment: I don't know what to put in: var newLinkRef = ...
I would have liked newLinkRef to be equal to replace

Comment: You'll have to show us more code, because it's hard to understand your logic.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `newLinkRef` is not defined. define it with `var`, set a value to it, and then you can call `.replace()` or any other method on it.

Comment: var newLinkRef = replace(linkRef, idMiniatureRef); I don't see how to write it

Comment: @edoc what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my concern, it was simply:

```
var newLinkRef = idMiniatureRef;
```

I was absolutely looking to put a replace () x)